# gmail contextual gadgets domain name

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am writing a Gmail Contextual Gadget,

Is there way to pass domain name using gadget xml
e.g

```
<Extension id="HelloWorldGadget" type="gadget">
  <Name>Hello World Gmail contextual gadget</Name>
  <Url>_http://example.com/gadgets/hello_world_gadget.xml?domain=${DOMAIN_NAME}</Url>
  <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>
```

**domain=${DOMAIN_NAME}**

any other way get domain name using API?

We have multiple CRM client and want to connect client DB based on domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I currently get the domain name by using this in the content section of the Module xml. Not my code, but I can't remember where I found the example.

```
var googledomain = gadgets.util.getUrlParameters()['parent'].match(/.+\/a\/(.+)\/html/)[1];
```